# Simplify for multiple products switching between image and information for each poroduct

Tags: javascript, html, css, function

The following code works to switch between image and information of 3 items click on that items image or info button, but thinking it is heavy handed duplication and there must be a better way to do the same thing, if i have say 10 items on a page, I would be duplicating the javascript 7 times with slight changes.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html> 
   <html>
   <head>
   <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
   function openDetail(detailName) {
   var i;
   var x = document.getElementsByClassName("detail");

   for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
   x[i].style.display = "none";
   }
   document.getElementById(detailName).style.display = "block";

   }
   function openDetail1(detail1Name) {
   var i;
   var x = document.getElementsByClassName("detail1");

   for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
   x[i].style.display = "none";
   }
   document.getElementById(detail1Name).style.display = "block";

   }
   function openDetail2(detail2Name) {
   var i;
   var x = document.getElementsByClassName("detail2");

   for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
   x[i].style.display = "none";
   }
   document.getElementById(detail2Name).style.display = "block";

   }
   </script>

   <style>
   #contact-form-shopo {width: 670;padding: 10px;margin  }
   #contact-form-shop-blank {width: 330px;padding: 10px;margin :0px 0px 10px 5px;}

   #contact-form-shop {background-color: #fff;width: 330px;height:250px;  padding:      0px;margin :0px 0px 10px 5px;border: 4px solid #3d4f59;-moz-border-radius: 15px;-webkit-border-radius: 15px;border-radius: 15px;float:left; }
   #contact-form-shop h1 {font-size: 42px; margin:0px 0 0}
   #contact-form-shop h2 {text-align:center;width: 330px;padding: 0px;margin :0px 0px 10px px;margin-bottom: 15px;font-style: italic;font-weight: normal;font-size:20px;border-bottom: 4px solid #3d4f59;-moz-border-radius: 15px;-webkit-border-radius: 15px; }
   #contact-form-shop img {  display: block;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;}
   </style>
   </head>
   <body>


   <div>
   <h2> Options</h2></p>
   <div id="contact-form-shop"class="clearfix" width="50%"><H2>CP</H2>
   <div id="imginfo">
   <button class="button" onclick="openDetail('CPIMG')">Image</button>
   <button class="button" onclick="openDetail('CPINFO')">Info</button>
   </div>
   <div id="CPIMG" class="detail">Image: CP<br><img src="/images/x.jpg" alt="CP Image X"></div>
   <div id="CPINFO" class="detail" style="display:none">Information:</div>
   </div>
   <div id="contact-form-shop" class="clearfix" width="50%"><H2>Pye</H2> 
   <div id="imginfo">
   <button class="button" onclick="openDetail1('PYEIMG')">Image</button>
   <button class="button" onclick="openDetail1('PYEINFO')">Info</button
   </div>
   <div id="PYEIMG" class="detail1">Pye<br><img src="/images/y.jpg" alt="Pye Image Y"</div>
  </div>
  <div id="PYEINFO" class="detail1" style="display:none">Information:</div>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div id="contact-form-shop" class="clearfix"width="50%"><H2>Rage</H2> 
  <div id="imginfo">
  <button class="button" onclick="openDetail2('RAGEIMG')">Image</button>
  <button class="button" onclick="openDetail2('RAGEINFO')">Info</button
  </div>
  <div id="RAGEIMG" class="detail2">Image: RAGE<br><img src="/images/z.jpg" alt="RAGE Image Z"</div>
  <div id="RAGEINFO" class="detail2" style="display:none">Information:</div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  </body>
  </html>
```

It is really simple the box for each item and the javascript flick between the image and the information for each item independantly when pressing the appropriate button, just seems very repetative and must be a smarter way of writing this.